# ReactJS Complex Form Input Field Duplicating Text in Multiple Input Fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form where you can add/remove groups and input items, I was able to get the groups of input field working, but I'm having trouble with the items input within the respected groups:

I created a code sand box here: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-cache-4ipv6?file=/src/Form.jsx

If you click on `Add Items +` button, and type in the item fields, the value duplicates to all the fields.

Also, sometimes I feel like the `x` button doesn't work, and will only remove the last item or something, I believe this is "controlled component?"

In addition, I want to ask if there's a better method on what I'm doing? It seems like there's a lot of complexities in the code I'm trying to write up. I feel like I'm writing too much of the set state hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we don't need that `fields` state.

And we can update Add Handlers like this

```
  const handleAddGroup = i => {
    const newGroup = [...group];
    newGroup.push({
      id: null,
      cat: "",
      items: [
        {
          name: "",
          value: ""
        }
      ]
    });

    setGroups(newGroup);
  };

  const handleAddField = i => {
    setGroups(state => {
      const stateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));

      stateCopy[i].items.push({
        name: "",
        value: ""
      });

      return stateCopy;
    });
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-frog-2yrlt

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! Can you help me understand this by explaining why you did JSON.parse and JSON.stringify together? Doesn't that just bring you back to the original array?

Also, do you think what I'm doing is okay, or are there better ways to do this? I feel like there's just too much code in this file

Comment: I've used JSON.parse and JSON.stringify again because you have an array inside the object, so if you use object destructuring, it doesn't copy the child array. It just copies the address of the child array. So I used JSON.stringify and JSON.object together to copy the entire object to a new one.